# Can I use Node.js packages, such as request, to scrape the AngularJS response on this WA government website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to go to the WA Secretary of State Corporations website (https://ccfs.sos.wa.gov/#/AdvancedSearch) to scrape data on newly incorporated companies.  All of this data is publicly available.

I filter the data by setting Business Type to WA PROFIT CORPORATION (towards bottom), Business Status to ACTIVE, and any random 30 day window for Start Date and End Date for the Date of Incorporation date range.  I then click Search.

The first thing I notice is there is no query string, so the DB isn't accessible via a query string.  So, I opened up Chome Dev Tools and went to the Network tab.  If you refresh the page you'll notice that there's an AngularJS XHR file that loads in under the Name GetAdvanceBusinessSearchList.

If I Preview this file, all of the data I need is neatly structured in JSON format.  If I try opening the file in another tab to see the query string I receive an error "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'".

I've tried accessing the data using the Node Request module.  I've tried both GET requests and POST requests.  I assumed POST was the correct route once I received the GET error mentioned above.  When fired off my POST request I also included some Form Data that I found in the Dev Tools, but the response I received was that it didn't support multipart/form-data.

I've also tried using the Puppeteer module, and I can get to the search results, but then because the content is loaded in using an Angular file, none of the HTML elements have IDs and it becomes a sloppy mess trying to mine all of the data.

```
const request = require('request');

request.get('https://cfda.sos.wa.gov/api/BusinessSearch/GetAdvanceBusinessSearchList', (err, res, body) => { console.log(body) });
```

My goal is to get access to the JSON structured data that can be found by previewing the GetAdvanceBusinessSearchList file in the Network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools once you've submitted a search.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to use some scraper that processes the web page in a "browser-like" environment since the page is probably not static - though, just because data is publicly visible in a web page does not make it legal to scrape and use in your own website, if that's what you're planning to do

Comment: Don't worry, I won't be using any of this data on my own website / application.  I do appreciate you giving me the heads-up, though!

Comment: I assure you I wasn't worried :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
curl 'https://cfda.sos.wa.gov/api/BusinessSearch/GetAdvanceBusinessSearchList' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es-AR;q=0.5,es;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://ccfs.sos.wa.gov/' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' -H 'Origin: https://ccfs.sos.wa.gov' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'Type=Agent&BusinessStatusID=0&SearchEntityName=&SearchType=&BusinessTypeID=0&AgentName=&PrincipalName=&StartDateOfIncorporation=&EndDateOfIncorporation=&ExpirationDate=&IsSearch=true&IsShowAdvanceSearch=true&&&AgentAddress%5BIsAddressSame%5D=false&AgentAddress%5BIsValidAddress%5D=false&AgentAddress%5BisUserNonCommercialRegisteredAgent%5D=false&AgentAddress%5BIsInvalidState%5D=false&AgentAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BFilerID%5D=0&AgentAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BUserID%5D=0&AgentAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BCreatedBy%5D=0&&AgentAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BModifiedBy%5D=0&&AgentAddress%5BFullAddress%5D=%2C%20WA%2C%20USA&AgentAddress%5BID%5D=0&&&&AgentAddress%5BState%5D=WA&&AgentAddress%5BCountry%5D=USA&&&&&&&&PrincipalAddress%5BIsAddressSame%5D=false&PrincipalAddress%5BIsValidAddress%5D=false&PrincipalAddress%5BisUserNonCommercialRegisteredAgent%5D=false&PrincipalAddress%5BIsInvalidState%5D=false&PrincipalAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BFilerID%5D=0&PrincipalAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BUserID%5D=0&PrincipalAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BCreatedBy%5D=0&&PrincipalAddress%5BbaseEntity%5D%5BModifiedBy%5D=0&&PrincipalAddress%5BFullAddress%5D=%2C%20WA%2C%20USA&PrincipalAddress%5BID%5D=0&&&&PrincipalAddress%5BState%5D=&&PrincipalAddress%5BCountry%5D=USA&&&&&&PageID=1&PageCount=25'
```

Comment: Rodrigoap -- I believe this worked.  I was able to convert your curl command into a Node request.  Thank you very much for the help.  I'd appreciate any feedback on how you were able to look at the request headers (etc) and know how to turn that into a request.  Specifically, how you found the dataString value.  If you're too busy, then no worries.  Can you suggest any resources that may help me learn?  Thanks!

Comment: @paoiherpoais  Make your selections in browser then open dev tools with F12 and goto network tab > hit the submit button manually and look at network traffic > look for POST request ending with GetAdvanceBusinessSearchList  > right click > copy as curl

Comment: @QHarr Thank you both!